# Can I sell games made with LibGdx on Steam

Tags: libgdx, steam

my question is pretty self-explanatory, there is any technical or legal issue in selling libgdx games on steam?

**EDIT**

It is possible to show some kind of evidence, maybe a exemple of a game that is made with libgdx and already is on steam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no technical or legal issue why you can't sell your LibGDX game on Steam.

However -- and this is not specific to any platform or library -- your game needs to be pretty good for it to get their attention.

Comment: thank you for your answer. hahah you are right, but we cant discard any possibility right?

Comment: Your real question is probably "well it's a Java game, will it work on Steam?" right? Spiral Knights is a Java game on Steam. So yeah.

Answer (score 4):

libgdx is under the [apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) meaning that you can use it freely in both for-profit, non-profit,open-source and closed source games. Selling a game on steam makes it for-profit and likely closed source so you will be fine as long as you read at least once through the apache 2.0 lisence (it's not that long).